Async/Synchronous request calls out of order for Browser JS
Using D3.js graphs, I'm trying to draw a path defined by a data array, but there is a TypeError when doing this.
Edit: through debugging, I found that the data array had not been fetched yet.
This is browser based JS for a static site. The code that calls the data load is here:
SPD2LMS_load()
data = Array.from({length: NUMWV}, (v, i) => ({wavelength: MINWV + i * STEPWV, sensitivity: parseFloat(SPD2LMS(MINWV + i * STEPWV).l)}));

(SPD2LMS is dependent on SPD2LMS_load filling out SPD2LMS_data successfully first)
Here is the code which loads the CSV data into SPD2LMS_data.
async function SPD2LMS_load() {
  try {
    const response = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "utils/SPD2LMS.csv",
        dataType: "text",
        success: function(response) {
          alert("1. Loaded LMS");
          resolve(response);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          reject(new Error("Error loading SPD2LMS.csv: " + textStatus + " " + errorThrown));
        }
      });
    });

    SPD2LMS_data = Object.values($.csv.toObjects(response)); // special line
    alert("2. Data initialized");
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error loading SPD2LMS data:", error);
  }
}

Debugging shows that:

JS enters the ajax request during the SPD2LMS_load call
JS exits the SPD2LMS_load during the request
JS runs data=Array.from.... This returns an error as SPD2LMS requires SPD2LMS_data to be defined.
Then, JS comes back to the ajax call's success handler.

So, essentially, the order of things is mixed up. I need JS to wait until the ajax request is finished before it moves onto the current step 3.
I'm new to JS and also async/sync so any help would be appreciated

Why are you acessing input output properties of your data when it has wavelength and sensitivity properties instead?

My mistake. Edited and fixed

The error is really hinting that data is undefined when you append the path.  You gloss over the important details of how you retrieve the data and then call svgElement.append("path")...  Can you update your question with that?  And be wary of trusting your console.log, chrome might not be showing you what that value is in that moment.  To see that do console.log(JSON.stringify(data))

I edited the question to include the definition of data. I also checked and confirmed that JSON.stringify(data) did print the correct array onto the console (same content as shown in the image above)

Edit: I did find that using the debugger, data was undefined.

Updated the question towards isolating the async issues

$.ajax is already an asynchronous operation, returning a thenable object. I'm not sure why it is being wrapped in a Promise.

jQuery has an option to make the request synchronous, so that it must finish running before JS returns to the parent block.
function SPD2LMS_load() {
  try {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "utils/SPD2LMS.csv",
        dataType: "text",
        success: function(response) {
          SPD2LMS_data = Object.values($.csv.toObjects(response)); // special line
        },
        async: false
      });

  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error loading SPD2LMS data:", error);
  }
}


Setting the async option to false was deprecated back in jQuery 1.8 . Now that we're on version 3.7, I think it's well past time to let that one go....

What would be a good replacement for it? In the case that this function is needed.

There is no replacement. You just deal with the asynchronicity. It takes time for a network request to happen; do something else while that time elapses. Show a spinner, calculate pi to an obnoxious number of digits, doesn't matter.
